# How can I suppress newlines within an output array when dumping indented JSON?

Tags: python, json

I have this code:

```
import json

my_list = [1, 2, 3]
my_dict = {"key": "value", "boolean": True}
my_json = {"object": my_dict, "array": my_list}

print(json.dumps(my_json, indent=4))
```

I get an output like:

```
{
    "object": {
        "key": "value",
        "boolean": true
    },
    "array": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
}
```

I want it the elements of the `"array"` array to appear on the same line, like so:

```
{
    "object": {
        "key": "value",
        "boolean": true
    },
    "array": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

How can I get this result?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `indent=4` ?

Comment: I guess you could use regex to search & replace. But how do you want to handle more complex JSON that contains lists & dicts nested inside other lists & dicts? To get complete control you can implement your own class that inherits from [`json.JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder).

Comment: Closed, but the link in the close message points to a much too complicated answer. Use this: `print(json.dumps(my_json, indent=None, separators=(",",":")))`, which results in compact one-line form `{"object":{"key":"value","boolean":true},"array":[1,2,3]}`

Comment: An overeager close in me opinion. It's a very simple question and the close hint points to a very complex answer. mgaert above provided a one-liner that does the trick.

Comment: what about when the array is 100's or 1000's of items in length? how are you rendering the json string? maybe you can use a different program to render and explore the json like firefox or chrome browers which allow you to expand and collapse the shelves?

Answer (score 10):

Your task can be fulfilled by using a library like [`jsbeautifier`](https://pypi.org/project/jsbeautifier/)

Install the library by using:

```
pip install jsbeautifier
```

Then add the options and call the `jsbeautifier.beautify()` function.

Full Code:

```
import json
import jsbeautifier


my_list = [1, 2, 3]
my_dict = {"key": "value", "boolean": True}
my_json = {"object": my_dict, "array": my_list}

options = jsbeautifier.default_options()
options.indent_size = 2
print(jsbeautifier.beautify(json.dumps(my_json), options))
```

Output:

```
{
  "object": {
    "key": "value",
    "boolean": true
  },
  "array": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Comment: Does the project have a repo? Can't find anything for it...

Comment: https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify, I think
Is linked on the homepage https://pypi.org/project/jsbeautifier/

Comment: awesome repo, it saved me an evening from reinventing a wheel.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any new module to solve this problem. The JSON output is a string type and you can use a `loop` and an `if/elif/else` to solve it as in the example below:

```
import json

my_list = [1, 2, 3]
my_dict = {"key": "value", "boolean": True}
my_json = {"object": my_dict, "array": my_list}

json_dumps = json.dumps(my_json, indent=4)

str_to_write = ''
skip = 0
for char in json_dumps :
    if (skip == 1) and ((char == '\n') or (char == ' ')) :
        pass
    elif (char == '[') :
        skip = 1
        str_to_write = str_to_write + char
    elif (char == ']') :
        skip = 0
        str_to_write = str_to_write + char
    else :
        str_to_write = str_to_write + char

print(str_to_write)
```

Unfortunatly, it also strips the space character inside the lists. The output is:

```
{
    "object": {
        "key": "value",
        "boolean": true
    },
    "array": [1,2,3]
}
```

Using `regex` module, you can keep the spaces:

```
import regex as re
import json

my_list = [1, 2, 3]
my_dict = {"key": "value", "boolean": True}
my_json = {"object": my_dict, "array": my_list}

json_dumps = json.dumps(my_json, indent=4)

start = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('\[', json_dumps)]
end = [m.start() + 1 for m in re.finditer('\]', json_dumps)]
original = []
alterated = []
for s, e in zip(start, end) :
    original.append(json_dumps[s:e])
    alterated.append(json_dumps[s:e].replace('\n', '').replace('    ', '').replace(',', ', '))
for o, a in zip(original, alterated) :
    json_dumps = json_dumps.replace(o, a)

print(json_dumps)
```

The output:

```
{
    "object": {
        "key": "value",
        "boolean": true
    },
    "array": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Comment: The problem with this method that typically you still want to indent the lists that have nested elements. E.g. list like `[ [1,1,3], [1,1,3] ]` you want each sublist to be on their own line.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but it's hacky and involving monkey matching `json`'s library `encoder.py`.

```py
import json
a = {
    "header": [["l","f","f"],["f","f","f"]],
    "data": [[1,1,3], [1,1,3]]
}
json.encoder.pretty_json_lists = True
print(json.dumps(a, indent=4))
```

Resulting in json like so:

```json
{
    "header": [
        ["l","f","f"],
        ["f","f","f"]
    ],
    "data": [
        [1,1,3],
        [1,1,3]
    ]
}
```

Patched `encoder.py` can be found here - https://gist.github.com/Andrej730/38febfb059e12f3e67fe72703414ccf9